# "X characters left" message can be misleading

Tags: bug, comments

When replying in a comment thread to the person who wrote the post, the `@person` part is stripped. However, the "X character to go/left" message is misleading as it doesn't take the stripping into account:

[image]

Even though the message changes from the "... to go" message to "... characters left", the comment can't be sent because it would end up too short.

Comment: The thing is, the limit is calculated on the server side (and then requested by Ajax), the character limit is being updated in realtime on the client side. I smell issues with this one.